# Openerp_bootstrap error

Tags: python, odoo, openerp-7

I installed openerp7.0 on ubunto 13.10 and after that when I'm trying to install `openerp_bootstrap` it is showing this error.

I use these commands to install

```
sudo easy_install openerp_bootstrap
```

and also use

```
sudo pip install opeerp_bootstrap
```

Error:

```
Searching for openerp-bootstrap
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/openerp_bootstrap/
Best match: openerp-bootstrap 1.0b2
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/o/openerp_bootstrap/openerp_bootstrap-1.0b2.zip#md5=c1c7eae4a5b47fe4c267a06087f1e232
Processing openerp_bootstrap-1.0b2.zip
Writing /tmp/easy_install-rmrv8d/openerp_bootstrap-1.0b2/setup.cfg
Running openerp_bootstrap-1.0b2/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-rmrv8d/openerp_bootstrap-1.0b2/egg-dist-tmp-vwo2g4
error: HISTORY.txt: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Although your question looks readable now after all the edits of other users here on Stack Overflow, your initial question wasn't really formatted very good, hence the downvotes. Because the question has some downvotes, the chance people will see the question is lower (Stack Overflow gives questions with downvotes a lower priority). You could close this question and try it again in a new one, and please spend a little bit of time formulating your question to make it easier for other people to help you. SO is a community and you have to show some effort before you can expect something back.

Comment: I donwvoted not because of the formatting, but because this is not about "how do I program this or that", not even about "how do I use this programming-related tool" but simply about "how do I *install* this broken piece of software", which I consider a bad fit for SO. The [bug tracker](https://github.com/simahawk/openerp_bootstrap/issues) of the software would be more appropriate for that, as indeed this problem has already been reported there.

Comment: True, although installing programming related software can often be non trivial and people may need some help with it. Also I think the author didn't realise this is a known issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/simahawk/openerp_bootstrap/issues/1). Perhaps you should try to install from a checkout of the [github repository](https://github.com/simahawk/openerp_bootstrap), or [download the code from there](https://github.com/simahawk/openerp_bootstrap/archive/master.zip).